Calculate scalar QED vertex using LSZ formula
I am self-studying QFT using the Schwartz book "Quantum field theory and the standard model", and I am reading chapter 9 about Scalar QED.
I am trying to calculate the following vertex using the LSZ formula and Wicks theorem, cause the book is very vague about that (It seems to me he's hiding the complexity):

I have found out in Greiner-Reinhardt book "Field quantization" how to handle term like $\phi(x)\partial_\mu\phi(y)$: basically it can be shown that you can pull out the derivative from the time ordering operator.
In my final result the sign is different, I got $ie(p^\mu_1+p^\mu_2)$ instead of $-ie(p^\mu_1+p^\mu_2)$.
It seems I have an extra minus sign that comes from the photon propagator in the Feynman-`t Hooft gauge, which is (equation (8.104) and (8.92) in Schwartz book):
$$i\Pi^{\mu\nu}(p)=-{ig^{\mu\nu}\over{p^2+i\epsilon}}\tag{8.104}$$
$$<0|T\{A_\mu (x) A_\nu(y)\}|0> = i\int {d^4p\over{(2\pi)^4}}e^{ip(x-y)}\Pi^{\mu\nu}(p)\tag{8.92}$$
Usually as far as I know, the ${i\over{p^2-m^2}}$, that comes from the propagator, cancel with the  factor ${{p^2-m^2}\over{i}}$ that comes from the LSZ formula, so my guess is that for photon the factor in LSZ formula is ${p^2\over{-i}}$, instead of the ${p^2\over{i}}$ that I am using and applies to scalar field.
I am struggling since a week to calculate the vertex for Scalar QED and I would appreciate any help on that (Note that I have not studied yet the functional method, cause in Schwartz book is covered in later chapters)
Moreover, I have read in the Wikipedia that "Although the LSZ reduction formula cannot handle bound states, massless particles". So it seems that LSZ can't just be used to calculate the QED vertex involving photon, and that would confirm Schwartz book is hiding the complexity
EDIT: The following suggested link seems to confirm my guess. For scalar filed the LSZ formula have a factor $(+i)^{n+l}$, while for photon have a factor $(-i)^{n+l}$. That makes the difference, cause in that 3-vertex there's only one photon so I get the factor $(−i)$ which clear the same that comes from photon propagator.
https://porthos.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~romao/Public/homepage/publications/Lectures/Lectures-TCA-c2.pdf

Sometimes signs like this can boil down to differences in convention, eg different metric signatures, different Fourier transform conventions, different gauges, things like that. Have you checked whether this could explain the difference you're seeing? The issue with the LSZ formula for massless particles has to do with infrared divergences, and while this is an issue for applying the formula directly, there is a known way to solve it that you'll learn. In QED, you can think of it as adding a photon mass and taking the limit that the mass goes to zero. This isn't relevant for your problem.

In many places in QFT, there's a tradeoff between giving you the full story right away and overwhelming you with details, and giving you the most important information up front with a promise to come back and clean up some delicate issues later.

@Andrew The metric signature is the same $(1,-1,-1,-1), I am using the Feynman-`t Hooft gauge cause in the book is stated this the gauge that is used the very most of the time. I have some doubts about the LSZ formula, cause in the book is calculated only for scalar fields, and I don't know if it's exactly the same for photon

It is pretty much the same as a scalar field, but with some extra polarization vectors introduced to contract with the vector field index. It's given explicitly on slide 46 here, for example: https://porthos.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~romao/Public/homepage/publications/Lectures/Lectures-TCA-c2.pdf

@Andrew Many thanks, actually there's a difference cause for scalar I have a factor $(i)^{n+l}$ while for photon is $(-i)^{n+l}$. I will check if that makes teh difference I need

As far as I can see that factor $(-i)^{n+l}$ in the LSZ formula for photon, which is different from the  $(+i)^{n+l}$ in the LSZ formula for scalar, makes the difference, cause in that 3-vertex there's only one photon so I get the factor $(-i)$ that clear the one that comes from photon propagator
